# Text appears in Chrome but not firefox?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have this CSS but my text is correctly showing in Google Chrome and Ie; but not firefox. I cannot figure out why.

```
input[type="text"] { width: 274px;  border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #181818; padding-top: 9px; color: #777; height: 13px; padding-left: 4px; padding-bottom: 8px;}
input[type="password"] { width: 274px;  border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #181818; padding-top: 9px; color: #777; height: 13px; padding-left: 4px; padding-bottom: 8px; }
```

Can anyone recommend ways to get this to show?

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="CheckCredentials.php">
Member Login <Br>
Username: <br><input type="text" name="Username"> <br><br>
Password: <br><input type="password" name="Password"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login!">
</form>
```

**Screenies**

Firefox:
[image: This is on firefox]

Chrome:
[image: This is chrome]

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Do you want the HTML side?

Comment: can you explain what is not correct? Or post a screenshot?

Comment: In Firefox 18 and chrome 24, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBnH7/1/) looks mostly identical.

Comment: It does not, I have updated withscreenshots.. I can confirm that both text boxses on both screenies contain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the specified height, if you remove the height parameter from the input the problem is solved.

**alternative (better imo) solution:**
The problem was the box-sizing property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

It was set to *border-box* which calculates padding within the specified height and width and 13 < 9+8 (top and bottom padding) so there wasn't space for the actual content(text). If you need to use specified height the best solution is to use:

```
box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box; /* Safari */
```

This will calculate the padding of the element outside of the specified height so now the actual height of the input will be 13+9+8px.

Comment: Perfect!The second edit has successfully worked! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `padding` text disapear cause of padding.

For same view set `height` to auto